# Get consecutive occurrences of an event by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm working with a DataFrame that has `id`, `wage` and `date`, like this:

```
id   wage   date
1    100    201212
1    100    201301             
1     0     201302
1     0     201303
1    120    201304
1     0     201305
      .
2     0     201302
2     0     201303
```

And I want to create a `n_months_no_income` column that counts how many consecutive months a given individual has got `wage==0`, like this:

```
id   wage   date     n_months_no_income
1    100    201212             0
1    100    201301             0
1     0     201302             1
1     0     201303             2
1    120    201304             0
1     0     201305             1
      .                        .
2     0     201302             1
2     0     201303             2
```

I feel it's some sort of mix between `groupby('id')` , `cumcount()`, maybe `diff()` or `apply()` and then a `fillna(0)`, but I'm not finding the right one.

Do you have any ideas?

Here's an example for the dataframe for ease of replication:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2],'wage':[100,100,0,0,120,0,0,0],
 'date':[201212,201301,201302,201303,201304,201305,201302,201303]})
```

Edit: Added code for ease of use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case two `groupby` with `cumcount` and create the addtional key with `cumsum`

```
df.groupby('id').wage.apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x.ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount())
Out[333]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
5    1
Name: wage, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Woah, that was harder than expected, but it worked like a charm, thanks ! May I ask for a bit of an explanation, though? I'm kinda lost on the second `groupby`, what is actually happening?

Comment: @JuanCJ that is getting the second group within group of id

Comment: But what's the grouping variable? You're grouping by the cumsum of all the rows that are not `0 ` in each `id`? So each group will be either one row that isn't zero or all consecutive rows that are zero? is that right?

Comment: Each time I think I'm mastering `groupby` I discover a new way to use it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The result has 6 rows, but the example `df` has 8 rows. For the second `id` group result is [0,1] while expected result should be [1,2]. Please notice second group has all `wage` rows equal 0. Can You correct me If I'm wrong please?

Comment: this solution has problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    col1=dd.wage.ne(0).cumsum()
    return dd.assign(col1=col1).query("wage==0").groupby(['id',col1],as_index=False).cumcount()+1

n_months_no_income=df1.groupby("id",as_index=False,group_keys=False).apply(function1)
df1.assign(n_months_no_income=n_months_no_income).fillna(0)

：

┌───────┬───────┬───────┬────────┬────────────────────┐
│ index │  id   │ wage  │  date  │ n_months_no_income │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │ int64  │       double       │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼────────┼────────────────────┤
│     0 │     1 │   100 │ 201212 │                0.0 │
│     1 │     1 │   100 │ 201301 │                0.0 │
│     2 │     1 │     0 │ 201302 │                1.0 │
│     3 │     1 │     0 │ 201303 │                2.0 │
│     4 │     1 │   120 │ 201304 │                0.0 │
│     5 │     1 │     0 │ 201305 │                1.0 │
│     6 │     2 │     0 │ 201302 │                1.0 │
│     7 │     2 │     0 │ 201303 │                2.0 │
└───────┴───────┴───────┴────────┴────────────────────┘
```